# Which Google API is Dropbox using to edit docs inside its own application?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I've been doing some research to find out which API dropbox is using to edit docs, sheets, and slides using google doc editors inside its own application. I've looked at Google Docs API, Google Drive API, and Google App Scripts I still don't have a clear answer.

From the looks of it files are uploaded to Dropbox, then can be opened in Google's editors and they are saved back to dropbox after editing. These files don't show in my google drive so I am assuming they are not being saved by Google.

Answer (score 1):

These API are correct. It's your assumption that is wrongful. Dropbox may act as a Drive application and these files are outside of your reach, nevertheless still within your Drive.
Here it's explained: [store application-specific data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata).

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. So does that mean when you upload a document to Dropbox and open it with google editor it uses up allotted space in both Dropbox and Google Drive?